# High Availability (HA) & Scalability for Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Microsoft provides best  practices ([Best Practices for Performance Improvements Using Service Bus Brokered Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh528527.aspx)) to achieve high throughput. According to it:

> Single topic with 5 subscriptions can achieve a message throughput of
>   up to 600msg/s (message size: 1KB) if all messages are routed to all
>   subscriptions.

To obtain higher throughput, we should use multiple topics. I need to implement Event Modal for a solution that will be used for 10,000 tenants.

Questions are:

1. How much scalable the Azure Service Bus can be i.e. how many transaction it can support per topic or per namespace?
2. Also do I need to care about HA or Microsoft will take care of it. As per MSDN, I need to handle disaster recovery but I couldn’t find any reference for HA.

We have already found the discussion on similar line in  [Azure Service Bus Scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173536/azure-service-bus-scalability) post, still the answer is not clear.