# Max throughput for Azure Service Bus Queue with Node JS library?

Tags: node.js, azure, queue

Using the Azure NodeJS libraries, I'm unable to receive messages off of an Azure Service Bus Queue any faster than 5 or 6 messages a second. This is orders of magnitude slower than what the official docs suggest. I'm using a Queue with partitioning turned off (as recommended here [Polling an Azure Service Bus Queue from an Azure WebJob using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089590/polling-an-azure-service-bus-queue-from-an-azure-webjob-using-node-js/)), reading in ReceiveAndDelete mode. Essentially I am just calling .receiveQueueMessage() repeatedly.

Based on this question ([Azure Service Bus Scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173536/azure-service-bus-scalability/22446077#22446077)) seems like others are also seeing 5/6 messages a second when using NodeJS. Is this pretty much a hard limit? Any known workarounds or optimizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the thread which you provide is awesome, and it seems to receive messages from Service Bus Queue in a pipeline workflow, which will receive the next message after finished receiving the previous one.

And as mentions on [official site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-performance-improvements/#scenarios) at High-throughput queue section under Scenarios stage, we can find the following points which are appropriate to your situation:

> - To increase the overall receive rate from the queue, use multiple
>     message factories to create receivers.
> - Use asynchronous operations to take advantage of client-side
>     batching.
> - Set the batching interval to 50ms to reduce the number of Service Bus
>     client protocol transmissions. If multiple senders are used, increase
>     the batching interval to 100ms.

To achieve these optimizations, we can leverage the [sample on Azure github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/serviceBus#how-to-use).

And to Maximize the throughput of a single queue. I have a simply test leveraging the sample code above and set the loop time to 10ms.
The result in my test is: it will get nearly 50 messages per second in ReceiveAndDelete mode; and it will get about 70 messages per second in PeekLock mode, shown at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues/#receive-messages-from-a-queue

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var azure = require('azure');
var serviceBus = azure.createServiceBusService(connectionString);

function checkForMessages(sbService, queueName, callback) {
  sbService.receiveQueueMessage(queueName,{ isPeekLock: true }, function (err, lockedMessage) {

    if (err) {
      if (err === 'No messages to receive') {
        console.log('No messages');
      } else {
        callback(err);
      }
    } else {
      callback(null, lockedMessage);
    }
  });
}

function processMessage(sbService, err, lockedMsg) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error on Rx: ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Rx: ', lockedMsg);
    sbService.deleteMessage(lockedMsg, function(err2) {
      if (err2) {
        console.log('Failed to delete message: ', err2);
      } else {
        console.log('Deleted message.');
      }
    })
  }
}

var idx = 0;
function sendMessages(serviceBus, queueName) {
  var msg = 'Message # ' + (++idx) + (' '+uuid.v4());
  serviceBus.sendQueueMessage(queueName, msg, function (err) {
   if (err) {
     console.log('Failed Tx: ', err);
   } else {
     console.log('Sent ' + msg);
   }
  });
}


var queueName = 'myqueue';
serviceBus.getQueue(queueName, function (err,res) {
  if (err) {
   console.log('Failed: ', err);
  } else {
  console.log('current msg count '+ res.MessageCount);
   // var t = setInterval(checkForMessages.bind(null, serviceBus, queueName,function(err, lockedMsg){}), 10);  //ReceiveAndDelete mode
   var t = setInterval(checkForMessages.bind(null, serviceBus, queueName, processMessage.bind(null, serviceBus)), 10);  // PeekLock mode
   // setInterval(sendMessages.bind(null, serviceBus, queueName), 100);
                setTimeout(function(){
                                clearInterval(t);
                                console.log('task over');
                   },1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: OK. I was able to get similar numbers with the code you provided. My code must have been running so much slower because as you pointed out, it was receiving messages entirely serially. Your code is doing a receive every 10 ms, where I was doing a receive, waiting to get that message, then another receive and so on. So I get strict ordering, but lose a lot of performance right?

Comment: Yes, actually, as the official guide refers, set the batching interval to 50ms will be appropriate. But in my opinion, you can set the Interval time a little larger than the handling work time. Beside, you need to be care of Recursion method in node.js .