# Azure + Node Js Service bus persistent subscription of topic

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, iot

Using node js i want to create persistent subscription for Azure service bus service topic. right now it is execute only once. Please guide me I am new to this. Thanks in advance. I am using following code to subscribe topic.

```
var azure = require('azure');

var azureConnection = "Endpoint=sb:My connection string"

var retryOperations = new azure.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter();
var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(azureConnection).withFilter(retryOperations);

serviceBusService.receiveSubscriptionMessage('mytopic01', 'mytopicsub', function (error, receivedMessage) {

    if (!error) {
        // // // Message received and deleted
        console.log(receivedMessage);
    }
});
```

Also I don't want to use setInterval function. I want to solution if message publish to the topic it should automatically trigger subscription.

Comment: receiveSubscriptionMessage is the method for receiving methods from a subscription at the subscription client level. Internally it polls the subscription. There is no server side push option.

Comment: I know it is client side method. but we have to manually call this method to get data which is published by the server. I don't want manual call to this it should be automatically called once data published by server.(i.e. Data should be automatically received after server publish data for the subscribed topic.)

Comment: it has to be executed at least once.  in any case node is server side js. it functions like a callback method. I have not personally tried this though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if your client application is an independent node.js application, we usually set up a cycle program to receive message from service bus in loop. 
E.G.

```
var azure = require('azure');
var sbService = azure.createServiceBusService(<connection_string>);
function checkForMessages(sbService, queueName, callback) {
  sbService.receiveSubscriptionMessage(queueName, { isPeekLock: true }, function (err, lockedMessage) {
    if (err) {
      if (err === 'No messages to receive') {
        console.log('No messages');
      } else {
        callback(err);
      }
    } else {
      callback(null, lockedMessage);
    }
  });
}
function processMessage(sbService, err, lockedMsg) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error on Rx: ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Rx: ', lockedMsg);
    sbService.deleteMessage(lockedMsg, function(err2) {
      if (err2) {
        console.log('Failed to delete message: ', err2);
      } else {
        console.log('Deleted message.');
      }
    })
  }
}
setInterval(checkForMessages.bind(null, sbService, queueName, processMessage.bind(null, sbService)), 5000);
```

You can refer to the code sample in the similar scenario at [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/examples/ASM/service-bus.md) provided by Azure Team.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: here you have used setInterval function. I don't want to use that. It will slow down my application. i am sending more than 100 request per second to publish. And want to subscribe the same real time. Using setInterval will be not able to handle that.

Comment: Azure SDK in Node.js implement with Rest APIs, via HTTP protocol, so currently we need to setInterval function. And you can refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111382/max-throughput-for-azure-service-bus-queue-with-node-js-library/34127328#34127328 for the receiving performance we discussed before.